# How to equalize any 2-point curve in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, pen-tool, anchor-point

I'm in the process of building a custom logotype, drawing each character using a combination of the shapes, the pathfinder and the pen tool and I am currently crafting the 'B' character.

I would like to know if there is a way to take any 2-point curve (a curve created from two handles) and quickly turn it into a perfect arc (i.e. where both handles are of equal length. Currently I am doing this optically: I look at each handle, try to measure its using grid view, then carefully drag out each until it looks good.

There are 2 problems with this:
1. my points do not always fall exactly on a grid intersection, so it is very hard measure properly
2. It is very, very time consuming

Using outline mode helps eliminate a lot of the screen clutter (fills, etc) so I can see better, but I do not have all the gridlines in outline mode and thus cannot make proper judgements.

Unless I am missing something, the arc tool won't help me here as I am trying to retroactively improve the evenness of my curves.

I have tried creating elipses/arcs and using them as guides but again the results are imprecise and it is time consuming.

Can anybody suggest a tool or a method by which I can more accurately and quickly equalize my curves/arcs.

Illustrator CC

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use a stroke, then use Object → Expand to create the lines?

Here’s a speedrun attempt at it. :)

[image]

But, if you actually want to snap the control points of the curve to a certain place, and have them both match, you can use guides. I don't think that's going to give you a nice curve though.

[image]

Comment: You can make the guide from the center  of rotation outward then it will work.

Comment: Great answer - thanks @MarcEdwards. I'm not sure if it solves my problem though. I want to easily/efficiently make 2 control points that are **pre-existing** equal in length, thus making a mathematically even arc in my stroke. See the screenshot [here](http://cl.ly/image/1d2x150a1d03/screenshot.png) (I've circled the handles in question in green — although they look even, they are not perfectly mathematically even).

[Here](http://cl.ly/image/3I3B2b07461G/Screen%20Shot%202014-10-29%20at%2010.55.57%20AM.png) is another example

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Anchor Point Tool (Shift+C) from the Pen Tool Drop down.
If you click on the point with this tool and hold shift whilst dragging, it will give you even handles.